# HA in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

let's imagine situation - I have HA cluster with 3 Control plane node, with CP endpoint floating ip adress. First node down - ok, no problem, switch ip dest and go on. Second node down, and cluster goes to unavailiable state. So sad

Question - is possible return cluster in avaliable state, after falled nodes will be up?
Because my previous expiriense said no

Thanks

Avaliable cluster after nodes up

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You turned all 3 nodes back up, what really is a problem at that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

It is possible to recover from 1, 2 or all 3 masters down.
Boot them.
Make sure etcd cluster gets back up, or fix whatever issue there could be (disk full, expired certs, ...)
Then make sure kube-apiserver gets back up. Next kube-controller-manager & kube-scheduler.
At which point, your kubelets should already be re-registering and workloads starting back up.

Comment: Ok, i have own cluster with  3 control plane on VM, if 2 VM down, and i recover that with previous state (with all control plane components, configs, certs, etc...), cluster will goes to consistent state?

Comment: depends what you mean by "recover that with previous state". If you mean restoring a DISK snapshot prior outage, I wouldn't. You have one master up: try to boot the others. If they don't join the cluster: reconfigure your last etcd node to work as a single-member cluster (remove the two other control planes), then reinstall your broken nodes and have them join etcd cluster, ... you may keep existing certs/would simplify recovery

Answer (score 0):

If you use a managed kubernetes cluster you don't have to worry about this, but if you're running your own masters you don't even need to worry about the floating IP.  You just bring up new masters and join them to the existing master(s) and you're back up to fighting strength.